# Join With Union in sql query killing performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-performance

Is there any way to improve the below query?

The below query is giving correct result but killing the performance.

Comment: Is each individual query slow too? do you have index on ID column? BTW, I think you need to use PIVOT instead of writing such a query.

Comment: You should start with having indices on ID and if you do not expect duplicate IDs between table1 and table2 you can replace Union with Union All

Comment: @FLICKER: Thanks. i have an index on ID. Is it possible through Pivot. kindly suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
Select 
  ID,
  max(case when MYDATE = '20160105 10:00:00' then PRICE else 0 end),
  max(case when MYDATE = '20140805 10:00:00' then PRICE else 0 end),
  max(case when MYDATE = '20170215 10:00:00' then PRICE else 0 end)
FROM
(
  select ID, PRICE FROM TABLE1 WHERE MYDATE in ('20160105 10:00:00', '20140805 10:00:00', '20170215 10:00:00')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, PRICE FROM TABLE2 WHERE MYDATE in ('20160105 10:00:00', '20140805 10:00:00', '20170215 10:00:00')
) A
group by ID
```

Guessing would be easier if you would have provided any examples...

Comment: maybe switch to `union all` to avoid the de-duplication?

Comment: Yes, that might be possible, depends on of course what the data is

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid a ( ) , use the A.ID for join  and this could  produce some benefit for performance

```
Select A.ID, A.[2016 Price], B.[2014 Price], C.[2017 Price]
FROM

  (
  select ID, PRICE [2016 Price] FROM TABLE1 WHERE MYDATE = 2016-01-05 10:00:00
  UNION
  SELECT ID, PRICE FROM TABLE2 WHERE MYDATE = 2016-01-05 10:00:00
  ) A 

INNER JOIN

  (
  select ID, PRICE [2014 Price] FROM TABLE1 WHERE MYDATE = 2014-08-05 10:00:00
  UNION
  SELECT ID, PRICE FROM TABLE2 WHERE MYDATE = 2014-08-05 10:00:00
  ) B ON A.ID =B.ID

INNER JOIN

  (
  select ID, PRICE [2017 Price] FROM TABLE1 WHERE MYDATE = 2017-02-15 10:00:00
  UNION
  SELECT ID, PRICE FROM TABLE2 WHERE MYDATE = 2017-02-15 10:00:00
  )  ON A.ID =C.ID
```